# JSON script only running in VS Code not HTML

Tags: html, css, json, visual-studio, debugging

I am currently coding a website and wanted to include a navbar at the top which is uniformly styled on each page. I came across a method to do this with json and my code is as follows:

```
<body>
  <div id="nav-placeholder">
    <script>
    
      $(function(){
        $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
      });
    
      </script>
<div>
```

I also have an external code referenced for this to work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

My nav.html holds the proper navbar with styling. When I use the visual studio Live Server plugin the website displays fine with the navbar. However when I open the HTML file from my hard drive (double click and open in chrome) it doesn't show the navbar.

What is causing this?
Regards, and thank you :D

Comment: Running from the hard drive causes a different set of sandbox rules. You won't be able to load resources from the internet this way -- check your console for details.

Comment: The problem might be that you can load external files with js *only* from a server! you can use pythons http.server or a npm package `serve` or similar stuff to open a server in the current directory.

Comment: Okay thank you all veyr much for your replies!!